# C++ Determine remaining space of hard drive

Tags: c++, .net, hard-drive

I am programming with C++ in visual studio 2010 and I was wondering if there is an easy way to get the remaining space of a hard drive in MB. I am making a program that records images and I want to be able to see the remaining space. I noticed that visual basic has the following:

```
Dim cdrive As System.IO.DriveInfo
cdrive = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDriveInfo("C:\")
MsgBox(cdrive.TotalSize)
```

Is there anything like this in C++? Thanks

**Edit 1:** Thanks for the responses guys, I have just finished work so I'll have a look at your suggestions tomorrow

Comment: You could use the same call in managed C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetFreeDiskspaceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx) is what you want to call.

Sample code [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/231497).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 functions to do that

**GetDiskFreeSpace**

**GetDiskFreeSpaceEx**

```
CString clString;
ULARGE_INTEGER ulFree;
ULARGE_INTEGER ulTotal;

GetDiskFreeSpaceEx ("c:\\", &ulFree, &ulTotal, NULL);
clString.Format ("%f", (double)(signed __int64)(ulFree.QuadPart) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024));
clString = clString.Mid (0, clString.Find ('.') + 2) + " Gb";
```